# gluing ideals together

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

While pondering basic facts about closed subschemes the following claim occurred to me . I think it must be true but I have trouble proving it algebraically.

Let $ R$ be a commutative ring with 1.  Let $f_1,...,f_k\in R$ with $ (f_1,...,f_k)=R$  and let $I_1\subset R_{f_1}, ..., I_k\subset R_{f_k}$ be ideals. Suppose that for each $i,j$, the ideal generated by the image of $I_i$ in $ R_{f_if_j}$ is the same as the ideal generated by the image of $I_j$ in $ R_{f_if_j}$.  Then there exists a unique ideal $I\subset R$ whose image in each $R_{f_i}$ generates $I_i$.

Comment: Hint: consider the exact sequence $0\to R\to \prod R_{f_i}\to \prod R_{f_if_j}$, where the first map is the product of the inclusions and the second map is the difference of the two ways to localize. (This is just the sheaf condition in algebraic terms.)

Comment: @KReiser Thank you .  Following your hint I tried looking at the preimage in R of the R submodule $\Pi I_i \subset \Pi R_{f_i}$.  But idk why that perimage generates each $I_i$ when you push it back down to to $R_{f_i}$

Comment: @KReiser is there an elegant way to use this sequence to prove the result? (/in particular is there a proof that avoids the computations in the answer below?) I'm probably just missing something but I don't see how to use it to prove the desired result

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Suppose we have an exact sequence $0\to M\to N\to P$ and a submodule $N'\subset N$ which is a subset of the kernel of $N\to P$. Then $N$ is the image of a unique submodule of $M$. Does this convince you?

Comment: @abba Pick a collection of generators of $I_i$. Up to multiplication by $f_i$, we can assume they're in the image of $R$, and this doesn't change the generating set since $f_i$ are units in $R_i$. These are certainly preserved after taking the preimage and pushing back down.

Comment: @KReiser sorry, what is $N'$ meant to be in $\Pi R_{f_i}$ though?

Comment: thats not in the kernel though is it?

Comment: I don't see that the condition implies that. maybe im being stupid. seems to me the condition doesn't imply *every* choice of elements of the $I_i$ glue together

Comment: e.g take all factors to be zero except a single nonzero one

Comment: @abba oh of course so sorry, you are absolutely right

Comment: yeah I'm not sure how the details of @KReiser's argument is supposed to go in this case

Comment: I think Atticus' argument is just fine and I defer to their answer. Apologies if I gave an unsatisfactory hint/argument, I loathe verifying the details of the gluing construction any more often than necessary and I did not check thoroughly enough to make sure the hint would go all the way..

Comment: @KReiser no worries, it got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: no worries @KReiser, it does seem like something where there "should" be a more elegant argument... lots of ugly computation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is possibly a much more elegant solution than this, but here is a (slightly ugly) proof.

For each $i, j$, let $\iota_i:R\rightarrow R_{f_i}$ and $\tau_{ij}:R_{f_i}\rightarrow R_{f_if_j}$ be the canonical localization maps. (Recall in particular that $\text{ker}(\tau_{ij})=\{x\in R_{f_i}:\exists b\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }xf_j^b\big/1=0\big/1\in R_{f_i}\}$.) Now, define $I=\bigcap_{i=1}^k\iota_i^{-1}(I_i)$. Certainly $I$ is an ideal of $R$, and each $\iota_i(I)R_{f_i}\leqslant I_i$. I claim that this inclusion is an equality.

To see this, let $r\big/{f_i^m}\in I_i$, where $r\in R$. Now, to show $r\big/f_i^m\in\iota_i(I)R_{f_i}$ it certainly suffices to show $r\big/1\in\iota_i(I)R_{f_i}$, so really we just need to find $s\in I$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $r\big/1=s\big/f_i^n\in R_{f_i}$.

To do this, fix some $j\neq i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. Note that $r\big/1\in I_i$, so $r\big/1\in \tau_{ij}(I_i)R_{f_if_j}=\tau_{ji}(I_j)R_{f_if_j}$, so there are $f\in I_j$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $r\big/1=f\big/f_i^a\in R_{f_if_j}$. Hence $(rf_i^a-f)\big/1\in\text{ker}(\tau_{ji})$, so there is $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(rf_i^a-f)f_i^b\big/1=0\big/1\in R_{f_j}$, ie such that $rf_i^{a+b}\big/1=ff_i^b\big/1\in R_{f_j}$. But then, because $f\in I_j$, we have $rf_i^{a+b}\big/1\in I_j$. Denote therefore $n_j=a+b$, so that $rf_i^{n_j}\big/1\in I_j$.

Now, do this for all $j$, let $n=\text{max}_{j\neq i}n_j$, and define $s=rf_i^n\in R$. Clearly $s\in I$, since (for all $j$) $\iota_j(s)=s\big/1=(rf_i^{n_j})f_i^{n-n_j}\big/1\in I_j$ by construction of the $n_j$. Furthermore, we have $s\big/f_i^n=rf_i^n\big/f_i^n=r\big/1\in R_{f_i}$, so this $s\in I$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ give us exactly the witnesses of $r\big/1\in\iota_i(I)R_{f_i}$ that we desire.

---

Oops, forgot to show uniqueness. First note that $I$ is certainly maximal with the property you desire; if $r\in R\setminus I$, then by construction of $I$ there is some $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ with $\iota_i(r)\notin I_i$. But then clearly the image of any ideal containing $r$ in $R_{f_i}$ is strictly larger than $I_i$, so there can be no such ideal with the property we desire.

Conversely, suppose that $J\leqslant I$ has the property we desire. So $\iota_i(J)R_{f_i}=I_i$ for each $i$. Let $r\in I$, and fix some $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$. By construction we have $r\big/1\in I_i=\iota_i(J)R_{f_i}$, so there must be $s_i\in J$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $r\big/1=s_i\big/f_i^a\in R_{f_i}$. Thus $rf_i^a-s_i\in\text{ker}(\iota_i)$, so there is $b\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(rf_i^a-s_i)f_i^b=0\in R$. But then, since $s_i\in J$, we have $rf_i^{a+b}\in J$, so let $m_i=a+b$.

Repeat this process for all $i$, and let $m=\sum_{i=1}^k m_i$. Now, this is where we need the hypothesis that $\langle f_1,\dots,f_k\rangle=R$. Indeed, in particular, there are $\lambda_i\in R$ such that $\lambda_1 f_1+\dots+\lambda_k f_k=1$. This gives $r=r1=r1^m=r(\lambda_1 f_1+\dots+\lambda_k f_k)^m$. Every monomial term after expanding the right hand side will have a factor of $rf_i^{m_i}$ for some $i$, and hence lie in $J$ by construction. Thus the entire right hand side is an element of $J$, so $r$ is too, and we have $I=J$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking for the ugly algebraic solution.  One can always wave one's hands and say "the local pieces glue together into a closed subscheme" but thats not very enlightening

Comment: @abba great, so glad to help! :) completely agree that sometimes the best way to understand something well is to get into the ugly/technical details